# Getting status value 1073807368 in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server

There is `DBCheckDown` stored procedure in the `master` database.

When I run below command, I am getting a status value of `1073807368` for the master database. Because of this value, we are receiving master db down alert, but the master database is not down. Not sure what does status value 1073807368 means. Can anyone please help me with this?

```
SELECT name , status
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 
WHERE status >= 500 
  AND status NOT IN (65544, 65536, 4259840, 4259848)
```

I tried below command to check master db status and we get value 1073807368 which is not present in stored procedure.

```
SELECT name, status
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 
WHERE status >= 500;
```

I just want to know what does that value means and how to resolve that issue.

Comment: Why are you using `dbo.sysdatabases` and not `sys.databases`? That old view is for SQL Server *2000* instances.